# How to export all files with a certain name from SVN repository

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

How can I get all files with a certain name from an SVN repository?

For example, let's say that the repository structure looks like this:

```
/root
    /branches
        /project1
            foo.txt
        /project2
            foo.txt
        /project3
            foo.txt
    /tags
    /trunk
        /master1
            foo.txt
        /master2
        /master3
```

What I want is to retrieve all `foo.txt` files from the repository. Is that feasible?

Comment: Do you use Windows or Linux?

Comment: I am using Windows.

Comment: In Linux there are (outside subversion) several command-line tools (`sed`, `grep`) which would be useful in your case. I don't use Windows so I don't have idea, sorry :(

Answer (score 0):

There is no native support for this but something like following can be tried on the windows command line:

```
for /f %i in ('svn list --depth infinity https://url/root/ ^| find "foo.txt"') do echo svn export https://url/root/%i --username user --password password >> export_list.bat
```

Single file checkout i am pretty sure is not possible but you can try and export the same.

The command above will list down all the svn export that you need to perform in an export_list batch file.

As export will overwrite the same filename hence I put it in a batch file so that you can rename or rearrange the file with your convenience before executing all the export commands in a single go.